# Trigger Jenkins pipeline from Gitlab webhook

Tags: git, jenkins

Just started with Jenkins and I can't seem to get how to properly configure SCM for pipelines since there's no SCM config tab there. I've added a webhook to my gitlab project, with URL

http://my-jenkins-server.com/git/notifyCommit?url=https://my-gitlab-server.com/my-repo.git

But when I visit that URL, Jenkins tells me

```
No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: https://my-gitlab-server.com/my-repo.git
```

which sort of makes sense because I haven't explicitly told Jenkins that my pipeline is tied to this repo, just implicitly in the Jenkins script:

```
stage('Build'){
    git url: 'https://my-gitlab-server.com/my-repo.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: '<some-hash>'
    sh 'cd linux-native; make clean all'
}
```

So how do I tell Jenkins that a PIPELINE is tied to a specific repo? Alternatively, how do I find the proper `notifyCommit` url for my pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you've enabled the [Poll SCM](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository) option, Git webhooks should function as they do for Freestyle jobs.

But you will need to run the Pipeline manually at least once before `/git/notifyCommit` hooks will work.

For Freestyle projects, Jenkins can fairly easily inspect the job config and see which SCM is configured. For Scripted Pipeline, Jenkins can't determine what SCM you're using (if any) until it actually executes the Pipeline.

Comment: @embedded_crysis Have you enabled the Poll SCM trigger? I just created a new job, enabled that trigger and added a simple GitLab pipeline: `node { git 'https://gitlab.com/…' }`. After the first run of the job completed, I was able to use `/git/notifyCommit`.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me - however, I have yet to do a successful build. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: Tried another pipeline now, which builds successfully. It still doesn't register the repo to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly uncheck "Lightweight checkout" (under "Pipeline") for the first git checkout to work correctly and the pipeline to start.